# Orchard: Restricted access pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, acl, orchardcms

Summary:

How can I create pages, only authenticated users can access?
(Like having a password-protected directory in old-style ASP.NET sites)

Background:

Writing a small-company site, where members of the staff should be able to insert/update/delete content.
The Dashboard seems faaar to complex and overwhelming for a non-tech content-author.

Idea:

Create a secured "folder" with simple edit features, only accessible after logon.

I know, I can hide/show regions,widgets, menus etc.. using layers.
BUT: This would not limit access if someone enters the correct URL, would it??

How to do this?
Thanks,
Reinhard

Answer (score 2):

There is a "View Content" permission exactly for that purpose. It's granted by default for everyone. You may change that freely, so only specific roles would be granted access to items of a given type.

Comment: I have seen this, but does it allow me to specifiy more granually which content is allowed/protected.. like which blog-entry.. maybe on a slug-basis like /public/* vs. /forbidden/* ?
Or is it just on whole ContentTypes or Modules ?
could not find this..

Comment: Yes, starting with Orchard 1.5, there is a content permission feature that allows control per item.

Comment: Where does this content permission system live?  I can't find it either on the page edit screen, or role permissions screen.  Do you maybe have a tutorial?